# FT232R custom eeprom - D2XX

Tags: eeprom, ftdi

trying to figure out how to read full EEPROM dump and flash it back without using any templates, M Prog and FT Prog.

Need a way to utilize extra space on eeprom for authenticating cables.

Basically trying to read/write to the area in yellow.

Best is a way to read full .bin, edit and flash it back, with 0 templates.

Any ideas?

[image]